# Change 'prefer canvas' setting per leaflet map

Tags: leaflet

I'm using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) (v 0.7.7). It expects setting L_PREFER_CANVAS as a script tag, which is global. I wish to create 2 maps on same page, one with L_PREFER_CANVAS  flag ON and once with OFF. How can I do that ?

1) I've tried setting window.L_PREFER_CANVAS before the map creation.

2) I've tried creating my layers with extended classes like this

```
var MyCircle = L.Circle.extend({
            statics: {
                CANVAS: true,
                SVG: false
            }
        });
```

then using 'new MyCircle' instead of 'L.circle'.

Neither of the two methods have the desired effect, even though the map is rendered successfully

I'm looking into leaflet code but i'm not very comfortable with its inner workings yet, due to lack of js sorcery know-how i believe

Edit: A thing that partly works is cloning the entire leaflet source under a new object (M.* instead of L.*), and keep my desired flag enabled for it. But its clumsy and breaks with plugins which add their functionality to L.* classes. Thereby requiring more duplication to fix, which i'm trying to avoid

Comment: Are you able to setup a fiddle showcasing your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Would recommend you look into migrating onto Leaflet 1.0, where `preferCanvas` is now a traditional option inside the map constructor...Among many other significant improvements.
[Leaflet API reference by version](https://leafletjs.com/reference-versions.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, its not something possible in near term for my project. I agree, this is the best way to go in long term. However, i'm currently looking to make some changes in leaflet.js code or override something created by leaflet for doing this. The leaflet code is forming spaghetti in my brain, thus looking for help on it. Thanks

Comment: What specific problems prevent you from moving to 1.0?

Comment: I'm told that there are leaflet plugins being used which aren't compatible with newer leaflet version yet

Comment: That can be true, however many plugin authors have some 1.0 branches in progress in their repos, I'd say it would be worth taking a look. But yes you may have some specific ones which are blocking you.